# Limit connection rate in Python Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

Is there any way to limit connection rate in Python Twisted? I need to simulate the slow dataline, with timeouts and optionally data loss and use twisted framework.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Twisted's token buckets?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.htb.html

Answer (score 0):

[this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/twisted-python@twistedmatrix.com/msg00389.html) proposes three solutions and discusses the two feasible ones -- the best one is to use `iptables` (or other, equally powerful and flexible firewall software, of course) if your OS supports such software (i.e., do the data rate limiting outside of twisted); if your OS has no such power at your disposal, a less preferable but workable solution mentioned there is

> 1) Create an dictionary {ip1:count1, ip2: count2, .} in the server, and
>   check the counts for each incoming connection. 
>   Disconnect with transport.loseConnection() if the threshold for ip:count is
>   exceeded.
>   Reset this dictionary to empty dict {} every minute with reactor.callLater
>   timer.

whose limitation is explained in the post as

> approach (1) will do an accept() of
>   the connection and then drop it,
>   giving the host on the other end a
>   syn/ack transaction followed by a
>   closed connection, and then it will
>   probably attempt to reconnect
>   immediately.

Comment: Yes, I saw this post.. Iptables is the last option.